# Unable to add an item using Jsom

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

i am unable to add a list item. I need to update a field if the item already exsits in a list i was able to compare the lists to see if the item already exists.  if the list does not exist then i need to add/copy the list item to the

I have figured out how to update if the item exists but i am unable to add if the item does not find a match.

please see the code below for more details.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var olist111;
    function AddToCart() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var sourceId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var source = web.get_lists().getById(sourceId);

        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        context.load(oList);

        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var spItems = [];

        //alert('debut');
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            //alert(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(currentItem);
            spItems.push(currentItem);

        }


        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

            for (var j = 0; j < spItems.length; j++) {
                // pass use ID + product name
                var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems;
                compareFun.done(function (data) {
                    var Match = data;
                    var tempstr = Match.split("#");
                    var compared = tempstr[2];

                    if (compared == '1') {
                        //alert("Item already exists in the chart");

                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var id = tmpstr[0];
                        var qty = tmpstr[1];
                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        var oListItem = oList1.getItemById(id);

                        oListItem.set_item('QTY', parseInt(qty) + 1);
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);
                    }

                    else if (compared == '0') {
                        alert("Item not in the chart");
                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
                        var id = tmpstr[1];
                        alert(id);
                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Hardware Catalog');
                        var oListItem1 = oList1.getItemById(id);
                        clientContext.load(oListItem1);
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);
                       // clientContext.load(oListItem1);
                        alert(111);
                       // alert(oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));


                        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        //var chartListitem = oList.getItemById(id);
                        clientContext.load(oList);
                        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                        oListItem.set_item('Title', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Item', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Product_x0020_Name', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Description', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Price', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Department', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.set_item('Branch', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);

                    }
                }).fail(function (sender, args) { alert('Failed'); });
                console.log("index" + spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
            }
            function Succeeded() {

                alert('Item updated!');
            }
            //context.executeQueryAsync(success);
            //   alert('done');

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to add!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function failed(sender, args) {
            alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function Succeeded() {

            alert('Item updated!');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function error(sender, args) { alert('error'); }
    }

    //function updateListItem(str) {
    //    alert(1);
    //    alert(str);
    //    var tmpstr = str.split("#");
    //    alert(tmpstr[0]);
    //    alert(tmpstr[1]);
    //    var Productname = tmpstr[0];
    //    alert('update');
    //    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    //    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
    //    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
    //    oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
    //    oListItem.update();
    //    alert('update 2');
    //    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //}

    //function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //    alert('Item updated!');
    //}

    //function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    //    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    //}



    function Compare(str) {
        //alert(str);
        var Addstr = str;
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
        var id = tmpstr[1];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

        var skillcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        //skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + str + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query> <Where><And><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Productname + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName + "</Value> </Eq> </And> </Where></Query></View>");

        var skillcollListItem = list.getItems(skillcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(skillcollListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            if (skillcollListItem.get_count() >= 1) {
                var listItemInfo = '';
                var listItemEnumerator = skillcollListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    str = oListItem.get_id() + "#" + oListItem.get_item('QTY');
                }
                dfd.resolve(str + "#" + 1);
            }
            else {
                //str = str + "#" + 0;
                dfd.resolve(Addstr + "#" + 0);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }));
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>

 <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems caused by your caml query, below code works based on my test,
developer tool would helpful for front-end script always.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var olist111;
    function AddToCart() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var sourceId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var source = web.get_lists().getById(sourceId);

        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        context.load(oList);

        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var spItems = [];

        //alert('debut');
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            //alert(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(currentItem);
            spItems.push(currentItem);

        }


        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

            for (var j = 0; j < spItems.length; j++) {
                // pass use ID + product name
                var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems;
                compareFun.done(function (data) {
                    var Match = data;
                    var tempstr = Match.split("#");
                    var compared = tempstr[2];

                    if (compared == '1') {
                        //alert("Item already exists in the chart");

                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var id = tmpstr[0];
                        var qty = tmpstr[1];
                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

                        var oListItem = oList1.getItemById(id);

                        oListItem.set_item('QTY', parseInt(qty) + 1);
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success,failed);                 
                    }

                    else if (compared == '0') {
                        alert("Item not in the chart");
                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
                        var id = tmpstr[1];



                    }
                }).fail(function (sender, args) { alert('Failed'); });
                console.log("index" + spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
            }
            function Succeeded() {

                alert('Item updated!');
            }
            //context.executeQueryAsync(success);
            //   alert('done');

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to add!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function failed(sender, args) {
            alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function Succeeded() {

            alert('Item updated!');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function error(sender, args) { alert('error'); }
    }

    //function updateListItem(str) {
    //    alert(1);
    //    alert(str);
    //    var tmpstr = str.split("#");
    //    alert(tmpstr[0]);
    //    alert(tmpstr[1]);
    //    var Productname = tmpstr[0];
    //    alert('update');
    //    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    //    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
    //    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
    //    oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
    //    oListItem.update();
    //    alert('update 2');
    //    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //}

    //function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //    alert('Item updated!');
    //}

    //function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    //    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    //}



    function Compare(str) {
        //alert(str);
        var Addstr = str;
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
        var id = tmpstr[1];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

        var skillcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        //skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + str + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Productname + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId+ "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>");

        var skillcollListItem = list.getItems(skillcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(skillcollListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            if (skillcollListItem.get_count() >= 1) {
                var listItemInfo = '';
                var listItemEnumerator = skillcollListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    str = oListItem.get_id() + "#" + oListItem.get_item('QTY');
                }
                dfd.resolve(str +"#"+ 1);
            }
            else {
                //str = str + "#" + 0;
                dfd.resolve(Addstr + "#" + 0);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }));
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>

 <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
```

Update:

Test code to add a item.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var olist111;
    function AddToCart() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var sourceId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var source = web.get_lists().getById(sourceId);

        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        context.load(oList);

        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var spItems = [];

        //alert('debut');
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            //alert(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(currentItem);
            spItems.push(currentItem);

        }


        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

            for (var j = 0; j < spItems.length; j++) {
                // pass use ID + product name
                var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems;
                compareFun.done(function (data) {
                    var Match = data;
                    var tempstr = Match.split("#");
                    var compared = tempstr[2];

                    if (compared == '1') {
                        //alert("Item already exists in the chart");

                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var id = tmpstr[0];
                        var qty = tmpstr[1];
                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

                        var oListItem = oList1.getItemById(id);

                        oListItem.set_item('QTY', parseInt(qty) + 1);
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success,failed);                 
                    }

                    else if (compared == '0') {
                        alert("Item not in the chart");
                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
                        var id = tmpstr[1];

                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        //var chartListitem = oList.getItemById(id);
                        clientContext.load(oList);
                        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                        oListItem.set_item('Product_x0020_Name', "Some Value");
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);

                    }
                }).fail(function (sender, args) { alert('Failed'); });
                console.log("index" + spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
            }
            function Succeeded() {

                alert('Item updated!');
            }
            //context.executeQueryAsync(success);
            //   alert('done');

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to add!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function failed(sender, args) {
            alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function Succeeded() {

            alert('Item updated!');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function error(sender, args) { alert('error'); }
    }

    //function updateListItem(str) {
    //    alert(1);
    //    alert(str);
    //    var tmpstr = str.split("#");
    //    alert(tmpstr[0]);
    //    alert(tmpstr[1]);
    //    var Productname = tmpstr[0];
    //    alert('update');
    //    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    //    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
    //    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
    //    oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
    //    oListItem.update();
    //    alert('update 2');
    //    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //}

    //function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //    alert('Item updated!');
    //}

    //function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    //    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    //}



    function Compare(str) {
        //alert(str);
        var Addstr = str;
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
        var id = tmpstr[1];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

        var skillcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        //skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + str + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Productname + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId+ "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>");

        var skillcollListItem = list.getItems(skillcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(skillcollListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            if (skillcollListItem.get_count() >= 1) {
                var listItemInfo = '';
                var listItemEnumerator = skillcollListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    str = oListItem.get_id() + "#" + oListItem.get_item('QTY');
                }
                dfd.resolve(str +"#"+ 1);
            }
            else {
                //str = str + "#" + 0;
                dfd.resolve(Addstr + "#" + 0);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }));
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>

 <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
```

I don't understand why you load a item from Hardware Catalog list while the id belongs to chart list.

```
var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Hardware Catalog');
var oListItem1 = oList1.getItemById(id);
clientContext.load(oListItem1);
alert(oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
```

Comment: lee i have updated the code, the updation seems to be fine but adding the item of the item does not exist is where i am struggling with .

Comment: Update the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you load a item from Hardware Catalog list while the id belongs to chart list. ?  . Because i am trying to copy the list item from the Hardware Catalogue to the chart if the item does not exists. it it does i simply update the QTY.  What i need is to add the items from the hardware catalogue. to chart . the above code add Some value

Comment: the addstr returns the ID of the item of the Hardware Catalogue from compare function as you can see i have copied it in the beginning. i was thinking to use this id to find the item useing getItemID method and add it to the chart hence the below code var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Hardware Catalog');
var oListItem1 = oList1.getItemById(id);
clientContext.load(oListItem1);

Comment: The compare function get ID from chart list based on your code.

Comment: I have updated the code for more clarity. initally i sent var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems; which is has the ID of the Hardware Catalogue . inside the compare function i have copied the same to var Addstr = str; if the item does not exist it returns  dfd.resolve(Addstr + "#" + 0); which has the original id of the Hardware Catalogue item not the changed one.

Comment: i use this id to copy the item of hardware catalog to the chart. as in the updated code above.

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  as always Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the below code.

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var olist111;
    function AddToCart() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);

        var sourceId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var source = web.get_lists().getById(sourceId);

        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        context.load(oList);

        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
        var spItems = [];

        //alert('debut');
        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
            var currentItem = source.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            //alert(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(currentItem);
            spItems.push(currentItem);

        }


        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

            for (var j = 0; j < spItems.length; j++) {
                // pass use ID + product name
                var compareFun = Compare(spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name') + "#" + spItems[j].get_item('ID'));
                olist111 = spItems;
                compareFun.done(function (data) {
                    var Match = data;
                    var tempstr = Match.split("#");
                    var compared = tempstr[2];

                    if (compared == '1') {
                        //alert("Item already exists in the chart");

                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var id = tmpstr[0];
                        var qty = tmpstr[1];
                        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                        var oList1 = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        var oListItem = oList1.getItemById(id);

                        oListItem.set_item('QTY', parseInt(qty) + 1);
                        oListItem.update();
                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);
                    }

                    else if (compared == '0') {
                        alert("Item not in the chart");
                        var tmpstr = Match.split("#");

                        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
                        var id = tmpstr[1];
                       // alert(id);
                        var clientContext1 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                        var oList1 = clientContext1.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Hardware Catalog');
                        var oListItem1 = oList1.getItemById(id);
                        clientContext1.load(oListItem1);
                        clientContext1.executeQueryAsync(success1, failed1);
                       // clientContext.load(oListItem1);
                       // alert(111);
                       // alert(oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));

                        function success1(sender, args) {
                           // alert('in ');
                            // window.location.reload(true);

                            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                            //alert(112);
                            //var chartListitem = oList.getItemById(id);
                            clientContext.load(oList);
                            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                            var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                            //alert(112);
                            oListItem.set_item('Title', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                            //alert(113);
                            oListItem.set_item('Item', oListItem1.get_item('Item'));
                            oListItem.set_item('Product_x0020_Name', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                            oListItem.set_item('Description', oListItem1.get_item('Description'));
                            oListItem.set_item('Price', oListItem1.get_item('Price'));
                            oListItem.set_item('Department', oListItem1.get_item('Department'));
                            oListItem.set_item('Branch', oListItem1.get_item('Branch'));
                            oListItem.update();
                            //alert(114);
                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);

                            //window.location.href = window.location.href;
                        }
                        function failed1(sender, args) {
                            alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                            // window.location.reload(true);
                            window.location.href = window.location.href;
                        }

                        //var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
                        //alert(112);
                        ////var chartListitem = oList.getItemById(id);
                        //clientContext.load(oList);
                        //var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                        //var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                        //alert(112);
                        //oListItem.set_item('Title', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //alert(113);
                        //oListItem.set_item('Item', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.set_item('Product_x0020_Name', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.set_item('Description', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.set_item('Price', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.set_item('Department', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.set_item('Branch', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
                        //oListItem.update();
                        //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);

                    }
                }).fail(function (sender, args) { alert('Failed'); });
                console.log("index" + spItems[j].get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
            }
            function Succeeded() {

                alert('Item updated!');
            }
            //context.executeQueryAsync(success);
            //   alert('done');

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to add!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        //function success1(sender, args) {
        //    alert('in ');
        //    // window.location.reload(true);

        //    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        //    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
        //    alert(112);
        //    //var chartListitem = oList.getItemById(id);
        //    clientContext.load(oList);
        //    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        //    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        //    alert(112);
        //    oListItem.set_item('Title', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    alert(113);
        //    oListItem.set_item('Item', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.set_item('Product_x0020_Name', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.set_item('Description', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.set_item('Price', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.set_item('Department', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.set_item('Branch', oListItem1.get_item('Product_x0020_Name'));
        //    oListItem.update();
        //    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failed);

        //    window.location.href = window.location.href;
        //}
        //function failed1(sender, args) {
        //    alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        //    // window.location.reload(true);
        //    window.location.href = window.location.href;
        //}

        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
        function failed(sender, args) {
            alert('Unable to update!' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function Succeeded() {

            alert('Item updated!');
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function success(sender, args) {
            alert('Added to chart!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        }

        function error(sender, args) { alert('error'); }
    }

    //function updateListItem(str) {
    //    alert(1);
    //    alert(str);
    //    var tmpstr = str.split("#");
    //    alert(tmpstr[0]);
    //    alert(tmpstr[1]);
    //    var Productname = tmpstr[0];
    //    alert('update');
    //    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    //    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');
    //    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(tmpstr[1]);
    //    oListItem.set_item('QTY', 2);
    //    oListItem.update();
    //    alert('update 2');
    //    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //}

    //function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //    alert('Item updated!');
    //}

    //function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    //    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    //}



    function Compare(str) {
        //alert(str);
        var Addstr = str;
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var tmpstr = str.split("#");
        var Productname = tmpstr[0];
        var id = tmpstr[1];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Chart');

        var skillcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        //skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + str + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        skillcamlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query> <Where><And><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Product_x0020_Name'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Productname + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName + "</Value> </Eq> </And> </Where></Query></View>");

        var skillcollListItem = list.getItems(skillcamlQuery);

        clientContext.load(skillcollListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            if (skillcollListItem.get_count() >= 1) {
                var listItemInfo = '';
                var listItemEnumerator = skillcollListItem.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    str = oListItem.get_id() + "#" + oListItem.get_item('QTY');
                }
                dfd.resolve(str + "#" + 1);
            }
            else {
                //str = str + "#" + 0;
                dfd.resolve(Addstr + "#" + 0);
            }
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
            dfd.reject(sender, args);
        }));
        return dfd.promise();
    }
</script>

 <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
```